# Callling a REST API in python

Tags: python, rest, api, curl

I want to call a REST api and get some json data in response in python.

```
curl https://analysis.lastline.com/analysis/get_completed -X POST -F “key=2AAAD5A21DN0TBDFZZ66” -F “api_token=IwoAGFa344c277Z2” -F “after=2016-03-11 20:00:00”
```

I know of python [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), but how can I pass `key`, `api_token` and `after`? What is `-F` flag and how to use it in python requests?

Comment: *"What is `-F` flag"* – It's possible to figure that out: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: you can convert: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 2):

Just include the parameter `data` to the .post function.

```
requests.post('https://analysis.lastline.com/analysis/get_completed', data = {'key':'2AAAD5A21DN0TBDFZZ66', 'api_token':'IwoAGFa344c277Z2', 'after':'2016-03-11 20:00:00'})
```

Answer (score 2):

-F stands for form contents

```
import requests

data = {
    'key': '2AAAD5A21DN0TBDFZZ66',
    'api_token': 'IwoAGFa344c277Z2',
    'after': '2016-03-11',
}

response = requests.post('https://analysis.lastline.com/analysis/get_completed', data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

-F means make a POST as form data. 
So in requests it would be:

```
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```